# SQL запрос с ограничением по дате отбираемых записей

Tags: sql

Запрос

```
SELECT coins.name AS Монета, coins.symbol AS Код, coins.count_calculated_profit AS Расчетов, coins.start_date AS [Дата запуска], Round(Avg([history]![difficulty]),2) AS [AVG сложность], Round([coins.difficulty],2) AS Сложность, Round([coins.coin_reward_day],3) AS [coin/day], Round([coins.price_usd],4) AS [Цена, $], Round([coins.coin_reward_day_usd],2) AS [$/day], coins.price_btc AS [Цена, BTC], coins.coin_reward_day_btc AS [BTC/day], Round([coin_reward_month_usd],2) AS [$/мес], coins.coin_reward_month_btc AS [BTC/мес], coins.url_wtm, CDbl([hashrate]![hashrate]*8) AS [8 GPU hash], hashrate.unit, coins.algo, Round([block_reward],3) AS [Block reward], coins.percent_change_1h AS [Час, %], coins.percent_change_24h AS [Сутки, %], coins.percent_change_7d AS [Неделю, %], coins.url_curr_loaded AS Цена, coins.url_diff_loaded AS [URL сложности], coins.date_last_update AS [Price update], coins.date_last_load_diff AS [Diff update], coins.announcement AS Анонс, coins.url_on_coinmarketcap, coins.wallet_status, coins.url_explorer_1, hashrate.miner, hashrate.intensity
FROM history INNER JOIN (coins INNER JOIN (unit INNER JOIN (gpu INNER JOIN (algo INNER JOIN hashrate ON algo.Код = hashrate.algo) ON gpu.Код = hashrate.gpu) ON unit.Код = hashrate.unit) ON coins.algo = algo.algo_name) ON history.coin_name = coins.name
WHERE (((coins.scam_or_token_coin)=False Or (coins.scam_or_token_coin)=False))
GROUP BY coins.name, coins.symbol, coins.count_calculated_profit, coins.start_date, Round([coins.difficulty],2), Round([coins.coin_reward_day],3), Round([coins.price_usd],4), Round([coins.coin_reward_day_usd],2), coins.price_btc, coins.coin_reward_day_btc, Round([coin_reward_month_usd],2), coins.coin_reward_month_btc, coins.url_wtm, CDbl([hashrate]![hashrate]*8), hashrate.unit, coins.algo, Round([block_reward],3), coins.percent_change_1h, coins.percent_change_24h, coins.percent_change_7d, coins.url_curr_loaded, coins.url_diff_loaded, coins.date_last_update, coins.date_last_load_diff, coins.announcement, coins.url_on_coinmarketcap, coins.wallet_status, coins.url_explorer_1, hashrate.miner, hashrate.intensity, coins.block_time
HAVING (((Round([coins.coin_reward_day_usd],2))>8) AND ((coins.date_last_update)>DateAdd("h",-3,Now())) AND ((coins.date_last_load_diff)>DateAdd("h",-3,Now()))) OR (((coins.coin_reward_day_btc)>0.001) AND ((coins.date_last_update)>DateAdd("h",-3,Now())) AND ((coins.date_last_load_diff)>DateAdd("h",-3,Now())))
ORDER BY coins.coin_reward_day_btc DESC;
```

Работает корректно, но считает в Round(Avg([history]![difficulty]),2) AS [AVG сложность] среднюю сложность за все время, не могу понять как переделать запрос чтобы при подсчете средней сложности учитывались только записи за последние 24 часа. Понимаю что нужно использовать конструкцию вида

(history.date_load_stats)>DateAdd("h",-24,Now())

но вот как ее "подружить" с моим запросом? Перепробовал несколько вариантов, все не компилируются(

Comment: И кстати, если раскрыть скобки в join и возможно записать их чуть в другом порядке, что бы используемые в ON таблицы встречались до join. И on писать сразу после очередного join то будет выглядеть гораздо проще, а работать точно так же

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но я сторонник принципа "работает - не трогай" :) Полезу - пол дня убью явно потом на восстановление)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Round(Avg(CASE WHEN history.date_load_stats>DateAdd("h",-24,Now()) THEN [history]![difficulty] END),2) AS [AVG сложность]
```

Если это MS Access (на что намекает символ "!" в имени поля), то

```
Round(Avg(IIF(history.date_load_stats>DateAdd("h",-24,Now());[history]![difficulty];NULL)),2) AS [AVG сложность]
```

Comment: Спасибо! Действительно это для MS Access, как-то упустил этот момент. Все работает отлично, только разделитель ",", а не ";" в IIF.

Comment: @ВасилийЕгоров В SQL-редакторе - да, запятая, а вот в построителе запросов - точка с запятой.